# How to create a responsive text within column in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've basically created a responsive website which is split into two. And I'm trying to add text in a row and 2 column format like so

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="centerBlock">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
        </div>
```

Sample of what I've done is given above. What's not included is an outer row and column class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to have the text overflow two a second column, or simply trying to create a two column layout?

Comment: @Fushniki Thanks for the reply im trying to create a two column layout. Sorry for the bad grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to simply create two columns, the below code will work.  You need to close out your div tags and you also need to use a class that ends in '6'.  ending in '4' is going to give you 3 columns.  each row is divided into 12 columns with bootstrap, so using a col-*-6 will divide into two columns each using half of the space.

```
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="centerBlock">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="centerBlock">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
      </div>
   </div>
  </div><!-- row-->
</div><!-- container -->
```